# defaultRowRenderer breaks jest unit test. ...Object.<anonymous> ... import createMultiSort

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-virtualized, unexpected-token

When I use *defaultRowRenderer* (method of *react-virtualized* for Table), *jest* unit-tests are failed with error:

```
...node_modules\react-virtualized\dist\es\Table\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import createMultiSort from './createMultiSort';
```

It can be reproduced easily.
Steps:

1. Install *typescript* app with *create-react-app*
2. Install *react-virtualized* and *@types/react-virtualized*
3. Add simple Table in *App.tsx*

   ```
   import * as React from "react";
   import { Column, Index, Table } from "react-virtualized";
   import { defaultRowRenderer } from "react-virtualized/dist/es/Table";
   import "./App.css";

   import logo from "./logo.svg";

   class App extends React.Component {
     public render() {
       return (
         <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
       </header>
       <p className="App-intro">
         To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
       </p>
       <Table
         style={{ outline: "none" }}
         height={300}
         width={300}
         headerHeight={40}
         rowHeight={40}
         rowCount={10}
         rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
         rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
       >
         <Column width={150} minWidth={90} label="Type" dataKey="Type" />
       </Table>
     </div>
   );
   }

     private rowGetter = (props: Index) => {
        return {};
     };

     private rowRenderer = (props: any) => {
         return defaultRowRenderer({
             ...props,
             style: { ...props.style, outline: "none" }
         });
     };
   }

   export default App;
   ```
4. Run test

Is there true way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did anyone ever fix this?

Comment: I still use workaround: cope function defaultRowRenderer from https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Table/defaultRowRenderer.js

Comment: Thanks @Artem, will give that a go, as currently I have managed to fix it using Jest `transformIgnorePatterns`, to ensure react-virtualized is transpiled by babel/webpack

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by telling jest not to ignore react-virtualized when running transforms, as by default all node_modules are ignored for transforms:

I have created a PR with the following edit to `README.md`

---

### Testing

As this library does not come pre-compiled, it requires to be transformed by your loader, otherwise you may get errors such as:

```
\path\to\src\node_modules\react-virtualized\dist\es\Table\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import createMultiSort from './createMultiSort';
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

To fix these, you must ensure `node_modules/react-virtualized` is transformed.
With CRA ([Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) and Jest you can either:
 1. Add a `transformIgnorePattern` to the `jest` config in `package.json`

Example `package.json`

```
 {
   ...
   "jest": {
     ...
     "transformIgnorePatterns": [
       "node_modules/(?!react-virtualized)/"
     ]
   }
 }
```

**OR**

2. Add the following CLI arg to your `npm test` script: `--transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!react-virtualized)/"`

   Example `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!react-virtualized)/\"",
  }
}
```